# Use ARC in simple class object-c

Tags: ios, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting, retain

I want to use ARC in my simple class where I store some values to pass into another class. And I want to know what reference I have to use in the property. To use it in ARC, I have this:

```
@interface MyItem : NSObject
@property (retain) NSString *valueID;
@property (retain) NSString *itName;
@property (retain) NSDate *creationDate;
@property (assign) float rating;
```

This is a very simple class, and I want to know how to use it in ARC. What reference do I have to use? Do I have to use a copy for the NSString etc?

EDIT:

If I have a UIViewController, and I want to use a property for NSString and for MyItem object like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyItem *newItem;
```

What reference do I have to use for NSString and for MyItem object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `strong` instead of `retain`. And yes, you should still use `copy` for `NSString`s. The use of `copy` has nothing to do with ARC; you want `copy` because if someone assigns an `NSMutableString` to your property you don't want the string changing behind your back. Using `copy` gives you an immutable snapshot of the mutable string at the point where the assignment took place.

---

This is the recommended way to declare the properties in your view controller example:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyItem *newItem;
```

The `NSString` could be declared as `strong` as well, but `copy` is almost always preferable for strings (and really any immutable type that has a mutable variant, e.g. arrays, dictionaries, etc).

Comment: .. now that's why people use copy on NSString properties. Had been wondering. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i have to use always copy for property in NSString ?...for example also in a UIViewController?

Comment: @Piero: You do not *have* to use `copy`, but it's strongly recommended. I'll update my answer for your specific view controller example.

Answer (score 3):

(nonatomic, strong) is what i use but here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)

or for quick reference

> Setter Semantics
>
> These attributes specify the semantics of a set accessor. They are
>   mutually exclusive.
>
> **strong** Specifies that there is a strong (owning) relationship to the
>   destination object.
>
> **weak** Specifies that there is a weak (non-owning) relationship to the
>   destination object.
>
> If the destination object is deallocated, the property value is
>   automatically set to nil.
>
> (Weak properties are not supported on OS X v10.6 and iOS 4; use assign
>   instead.)
>
> **copy** Specifies that a copy of the object should be used for
>   assignment.
>
> The previous value is sent a release message.
>
> The copy is made by invoking the copy method. This attribute is valid
>   only for object types, which must implement the NSCopying  protocol.
>
> **assign** Specifies that the setter uses simple assignment. This
>   attribute is the default.
>
> You use this attribute for scalar types such as NSInteger and CGRect.
>
> **retain** Specifies that retain should be invoked on the object upon
>   assignment.
>
> **Atomicity**
>
> You can use this attribute to specify that accessor methods are not
>   atomic. (There is no keyword to denote atomic.)
>
> **nonatomic** Specifies that accessors are nonatomic. By default,
>   accessors are atomic.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the documentation is very useful, i haven't find that first...thanks!